# Logstash grok filter help - hexedecimal?

Tags: hex, logstash, logstash-grok

Ok im fishing out, amongst other things, the first segment of a unique ID from a log line with a grok filter, like this (Its only the first segment that I care about, throw away the rest). This segment is hex ,and I want it in binary.

The line:

```
Transaction: 000178ec-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The filter is like :

```
Transaction: %{BASE16NUM:transaction_id}-%{GREEDYDATA:otherpartsidontcareabout}
```

But it just gives me this result:

```
{
  "transaction_id": [
  [
    "000178ec"
  ],
  "otherpartsidontcareabout":
  [
    "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ]]
}
```

Where I had expected it to be transformed into decimal:

```
{
  "transaction_id": [
  [
    "96492"
  ],
  "otherpartsidontcareabout":
  [
    "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ]]
}
```

Am I doing this wrong? Im really stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BASE16NUM` just indicates the pattern of the text.  To convert it to an integer you are going to have to do something like this:

```
filter { 
  ruby { 
    code => "event['transaction_id'] = event['transaction_id'].hex"
  } 
}
```

or for logstash 5

```
filter { 
  ruby { 
    code => "event.set('transaction_id', event.get('transaction_id').hex)" 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill try this tomorrow morning.